# Assembly (MASM) running program with byte value parameters?

Tags: assembly, command-line-arguments, masm, irvine32

I am writing an assembly program that will require a String and an array of bytes as run time arguments. (The bytes are not fixed to character values and are all unsigned values between 0and 255)

Example execution command:

```
     Program.exe "A 32 byte array (fixed size)" "A Byte array of arbitrary length, (greater than 0)"
```

How do I get the arguments in assembly?  also slightly irrelevant from the question, the array of bytes can be any length, will there be a problem if the length of the array is larger than a certain size?.  the arguments will be loaded into memory at run time and changed as the program executes then it returns the array in its new state.  (I am using assembly to speed up processing times)

Comment: Have you already written this program in another language and found it to be too slow?

Comment: Ive done conceptual work in java but do not have it on me at the moment, essentially I am using an encryption algorithm, the main program will use this assembly program as an external application to faster process data then return it back to the main application the main app will execute this and wait for the responce rather than process the data itself.  unfortunately i know much more Java than ASM but working with it will help me become more proficient with it.

Comment: This depends on the operating system you are programming for. Please tell us at least the .MODEL directive e.g. `.MODEL small` or `.MODEL flat`.

Comment: .Model flat, building for 32 bit processors .386 archetecture, although I can change it if another model works better, I don't really know much about what the model actually does, the book I have tends to stick with flat (kip irvine, assembly language for x86 processors 7th ED).

Answer (score 2):

For getting the arguments in a list like argv in C you need a shell32.lib which is not shipped with Irvine's book (as far as I can see in the free samples). You can get an appropriate shell32.lib here: http://www.masm32.com. When you have installed Masm32 you can play with my example:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

IncludeLib C:\masm32\lib\shell32.lib
GetCommandLineW PROTO STDCALL
CommandLineToArgvW PROTO STDCALL, :DWORD, :DWORD
WideCharToMultiByte PROTO STDCALL :DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD

.DATA
    szArglist   dd ?
    nArgs       dd ?
    arg         db 8192 dup (?) ; http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/10/56028.aspx

.CODE
main PROC

    invoke GetCommandLineW
    invoke CommandLineToArgvW, eax, OFFSET nArgs
    test eax, eax
    jz @@exit

    mov [szArglist], eax        ; Store the result of CommandLineToArgvW for LocalFree
    mov esi, [eax]              ; esi: *szArglist

    @@:
    invoke WideCharToMultiByte, 0,0,esi,-1,OFFSET arg,SIZEOF arg,0,0
    mov edx, OFFSET arg
    call   writeString          ; Write string to console (Irvine)
    call   CRLF                 ; New line on console (Irvine)

    shl eax, 1                  ; Result from WideCharToMultiByte multiplied by 2 due to Unicode
    add esi, eax                ; *szArglist += eax
    sub dword ptr [nArgs], 1    ; Further arguments in the list?
    jnz @B                      ; yes -> once more

    invoke LocalFree, dword ptr [szArglist] ; Free the memory occupied by CommandLineToArgvW

    @@exit:
    exit                        ; Irvine's exit

main ENDP

END main
```

I suggest to separate the elements of the array by spaces:

`Program.exe "A 32 byte array (fixed size)" 1 2 3 4 5`

Comment: Thanks, ill look into this within the next day or so, just got a pile of work i have to power through at the moment, ill get back to you though.